# Get all URLs from JSON with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, url, extract

how can I extract all URLs from JSON response with ruby?
I have an URL (test.testurl.de/test?p=12) which returns an JSON, e.g.

```
...
images: [
{
path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/z.jpg",
format: "image/jpeg",
},
{
path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/y.jpg",
format: "image/jpeg",
},
{
path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/x.jpg",
format: "image/jpeg",
},
...
```

If I try to extract via:

```
test = open("test.testurl.de/test?p=12").read
puts URI.extract(test)
```

then I just get:

```
["http:", "http:", "http:"]
```

Can anybody tell me why I won't get the whole URLs?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an HTTP client, such as HTTParty, Typhoeus, or better yet Faraday.

However, if you want to roll your own use the JSON gem to parse the response with something like:

```
response = open("test.testurl.de/test?p=12").read
parsed = JSON.parse(response) rescue {}
parsed['images'].map { |image| image['path'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
images: [
{
path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/z.jpg",
format: "image/jpeg",
},
...
...
```

Your string is not json, so you can't parse it as json. Is that really what's returned?

> If I try to extract via:
>
> ```
> test = open("test.testurl.de/test?p=12").read
> puts URI.extract(test)
> ```
>
> then I just get:
>
> ```
> ["http:", "http:", "http:"]
> ```

I get something different:

```
require 'uri'

str =<<END_OF_JUNK
images: [
  {
    path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/z.jpg",
    format: "image/jpeg", 
  },

  {
    path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/y.jpg",
    format: "image/jpeg",
  },

  {
    path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/x.jpg",
    format: "image/jpeg",
  }
]
END_OF_JUNK

p URI.extract(str)


--output:--
["path:", "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/z.jpg", "format:", "path:", "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/y.jpg", "format:", "path:", "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/x.jpg", "format:"]
```

With that output, I can do:

```
results = results.select do |url|
  url.start_with? "http"
end

p results

--output:--
["http://static.mydomain.de/pics/z.jpg", "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/y.jpg", "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/x.jpg"]
```

But if what you posted is, say, part of a ruby hash that gets converted to json:

```
require 'json'
require 'uri'

hash = {
  images: [
    {
      path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/z.jpg",
      format: "image/jpeg", 
    },

    {
      path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/y.jpg",
      format: "image/jpeg",
    },

    {
      path: "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/x.jpg",
      format: "image/jpeg",
    }
  ]
}

str = JSON.dump(hash)
p str

--output:--
"{\"images\":[{\"path\":\"http://static.mydomain.de/pics/z.jpg\",\"format\":\"image/jpeg\"},{\"path\":\"http://static.mydomain.de/pics/y.jpg\",\"format\":\"image/jpeg\"},{\"path\":\"http://static.mydomain.de/pics/x.jpg\",\"format\":\"image/jpeg\"}]}"
```

Then you can do this:

```
results = URI.extract(str)
p results

--output:--
["http://static.mydomain.de/pics/z.jpg", "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/y.jpg", "http://static.mydomain.de/pics/x.jpg"]
```